# How to create a function that concatenates a variable number of matrices?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, keyword-argument

I would like to create a python function to concatenate several matrix this is the example for two matrix:

```
def create_matrix(number,rows,columns):
    matrix=np.full((rows,columns),number)
    return matrix

matrix1=create_matrix(0,1,2)
matrix2=create_matrix(1,1,3)
matrix3=create_matrix(2,1,4)

def concatenate_matrix(matrix1,matrix2):
    vector_pacient=np.hstack((matrix1,matrix2))
    return vector_pacient

print(concatenate_matrix(matrix1,matrix2))
print('result',concatenate_matrix(matrix1,matrix2).shape)
```

This works very well for two matrices I got:

```
[[0 0 1 1 1]]
result shape (1, 5)
```

as I wanted, now I want to concatenate a variable number of matrices, I tried:

```
def concatenate_matrix2(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg.shape)
        vector_pacient=np.hstack(arg)
    return vector_pacient
print(concatenate_matrix2(matrix1,matrix2,matrix3))
print(concatenate_matrix2(matrix1,matrix2,matrix3).shape)
```

however I got:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
[2 2 2 2]
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
result shape (4,)
```

I don't understad where is the error, it should have a shape of:

```
(1,9)
```

and a matrix as follows:

```
[[0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]]
```

So I would like to appreciate suggestions to fix my code.

Comment: Why don't you just pass a list of arrays to `concatenate` or one the `stack` variants?

Comment: `np.concatenate((matrix1, matrix2, matrix3), axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error with your `for` loop. It seems you want to do the following:

```
def concatenate_matrix2(*args):
    vector_pacient = args[0]
    for i in range(1, len(args)):
        vector_pacient = np.hstack((vector_pacient, args[i]))
    return vector_pacient
```

or more succinctly:

```
def concatenate_matrix2(*args):
    return np.hstack(args)
```

or also:

```
def concatenate_matrix2(*args):
    return np.concatenate(args, axis=1)
```

(... which work only if the dimensions of all matrices except for the concatenation axis match exactly - it works here since the dimensions `0` have the same size `1`)

Answer (score 0):

For fun and also as an alternative that could be faster as well, why not create an "empty" concatenated array and then simply fill it with the data?

```
concat = np.empty((1, 9), dtype=np.int)
matrix1 = concat[0, :2]
matrix2 = concat[0, 2:5]
matrix3 = concat[0, 5:]

matrix1[:] = 0
matrix2[:] = 1
matrix3[:] = 2
```

Of course this can be "automated":

```
from itertools import accumulate
sl = ((2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2)) # define lengths of sections and values
cnt = [0] + list(accumulate(i[0] for i in sl))
for k, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(cnt[:-1], cnt[1:])):
    concat[0, i:j] = sl[k][1]
```